# Vue - how can i update the default value of an input text field?

Tags: vue.js

I'm loading a form component more times in the same page, that's because i have more forms for different tasks, so each form has different parameters.

Html page:

```
<div id="app">
  <myForm formType="buy"></myForm>
  <myForm formType="sell"></myForm>
  <myForm formType="submit"></myForm>
  <refreshAmount></refreshAmount>
</div>
```

And this is the form component:

```
<template>
  <div>
      
      <div v-if="formType=='buy'">
        
        <form @submit.prevent="formSubmit()">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="testetete" v-bind:value="amount">

        <button v-if="side==='buy'" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%">BUY</button>

        <p>Available amount: {{$store.getters.amount}}</p>
        </form>

      </div>

      ...


  </div>

</template>
     
<script>

export default {

  props:{

    formType:{
      type:String, 
      default:'buy'
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted')
  },

  data() {
    return {
      amount: this.$store.getters.amount

    }
      
  },
  methods: {
    ...
  }
}
</script>
```

Then i have the following store:

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    amount: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    refreshAmount(state) {

      fetch('SOME-URL')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          
          state.amount = 100
          //state.amount = data['amount']

        })
    }
  },
  getters: {
    amount: state => state.amount,
  }
})
</script>
```

And finally, the `refreshAmount` component:

```
...
mounted() {
    this.$store.commit('refreshBalance')
  }
...
```

Basically, i need to show an amount in the form component. This amount is retrieved from my backend, and since i'm loading the form component 3 times, i would call my backend 3 times while i only need to call it once, so i decided to create the component `refreshAmount` that would call it once and pass it to the form components using a Vuex store.

The problem with my code is the following:

When i load the page, i'll see **Available amount: 100** on all the 3 components, so that works; but in the default value of the text input form the value is **0**. Why is that? Why isn't the value inside the input text field updated while `<p>Available amount: {{$store.getters.amount}}</p>` is updated?

Tl;dr: i'm using Vuex to set the value of a variable in my components, when i load the variable between a `<p>` tag the value is refreshed, while inside the input field the value of the variable stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amount` is not updated because it's a data property, which only gets initialized when the component is first set up and not updated after. What you need is a `computed` property, which will keep track of the changes in the Vuex store. So instead of:

```js
data() {
  return {
    amount: this.$store.getters.amount
  } 
}
```

you can do:

```js
computed: {
  amount() {
    return this.$store.getters.amount
  }
}
```